# Use Case Template; Render enumerated list received from parameter

Tags: tables, enumerate, itemize, templates, parameters

## Desired Behavior

This Latex:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{usecases}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Example Use Case}

\begin{usecase}
    \name{Some Use Case Name}
    \actor{User}
    \description{This is some very complex use case}
    \precondition{X has to be true}
    \scenario{
        \item System show something
        \item User do this
        \item System do that
    }
    \result{Something happens}
    \extension{
        \item[3a] If something do something
    }
    \exceptions{
        \item[2.1] System message: "Nope"
        \item[2.2] System message: "Bad action"
    }
\end{usecase}

\end{document}
```

would produce this:

[image: desired use case table]

Note: the table should span the entire width of writable area of the document.

---

## What I currently have

Currently I am creating a `usecases.sty` package and I got this:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

% template %
\newcommand\addrow[2]{#1 & #2\\ \hline}

\newcommand\additemizedrow[2]{#1 &
        \begin{enumerate}
            \forcsvlist{\item}{#2}
        \end{enumerate}
        \\}

% making stuff convenient %
\newcommand\name[1]{\addrow{Name}{#1}}
\newcommand\actor[1]{\addrow{Actor}{#1}}
\newcommand\udescription[1]{\addrow{Description}{#1}}
\newcommand\precondition[1]{\addrow{Precondition}{#1}}
\newcommand\scenario[1]{\additemizedrow{Scenario}{#1}}
\newcommand\result[1]{\addrow{Result}{#1}}
\newcommand\extensions[1]{\additemizedrow{Extensions}{#1}}
\newcommand\exceptions[1]{\additemizedrow{Exceptions}{#1}}


\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\newenvironment{usecase}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{|s|b|}\hline}{\endtabularx}
```

---

## My questions (the issues)

How to render enumarted list properly when getting them as a parameter? (referring to my `additemizedrow` command which does not work as intended)

How to make the table width to span the entire writable area of the document? (The left column would have fixed size)

How to add some inner margin in the table's cell (see the image above)?

Comment: Regarding the overall width of the table:  take a look at the tabularx package.

Comment: Regarding "inner margins" : I guess you refer to the vertical white space between an hline and the text. For this, take a look at the cellspace package.

Comment: @leandriis I am trying out tabularx package by changing the `newenvironment` line to: `\newenvironment{usecase}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}\hline}{\end{tabularx}}` but I am getting *fatal error*

Comment: You can not use `\begin{tabularx}` and `\end{tabularx}` inside of the definition of a new environment. Instead, you could use the following code `\newenvironment{usecase}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{|l|X|}\hline}{\endtabularx}`.

Comment: Regarding your recent update: The `l` type column does not accept a width argument. Either use `l` as it is and accept that the column is automatically as wide as its widest entry or use `wl{2cm}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the desired output:

[image]

In comparison to your original code, I used the `enumitem` package to define a customized `enumerate`-like environment for which I changed the spacing above and below as well as the left margin/indentation.
In order to make the table as wide as the textwidt, I used the `tabularx` package.
To fix the width of the first column I used `wl` from the `array` package, which in turn is already loaded by `tabularx`. (This solution does not allow for linebreaks inside the first column. If you want thatn, replace `wl{2cm}` with `p{2cm}`.)
To increase the spacing between the text inside the cells and the `\hline`s , I used the `cellspace` package. You can of course customize this space according to your needs.
If you expect your table to exceed one page, you can use the `xltabular` package instead of `tabularx`. (With this approach, keep in mind that page breaks can only occur between subsequent table rows, not within a table row.)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  labelwidth=2em, 
                  leftmargin=2em, 
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

% template %
\newcommand\addrow[2]{#1 & #2\\ \hline}

\newcommand\additemizedrow[2]{#1 &
        \begin{tabenum}
            #2
        \end{tabenum}
        \\ \hline}

% making stuff convenient %
\newcommand\name[1]{\addrow{Name}{#1}}
\newcommand\actor[1]{\addrow{Actor}{#1}}
\newcommand\udescription[1]{\addrow{Description}{#1}}
\newcommand\precondition[1]{\addrow{Precondition}{#1}}
\newcommand\scenario[1]{\additemizedrow{Scenario}{#1}}
\newcommand\result[1]{\addrow{Result}{#1}}
\newcommand\extensions[1]{\additemizedrow{Extensions}{#1}}
\newcommand\exceptions[1]{\additemizedrow{Exceptions}{#1}}

\newenvironment{usecase}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{|0{wl{3cm}}|0{X}|}\hline}{\endtabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Example Use Case}

\begin{usecase}
    \name{Some Use Case Name}
    \actor{User}
    \udescription{This is some very complex use case}
    \precondition{X has to be true}
    \scenario{
        \item System show something
        \item User do this
        \item System do that
    }
    \result{Something happens}
    \extensions{
        \item[3a] If something do something
    }
    \exceptions{
        \item[2.1] System message: "Nope"
        \item[2.2] System message: "Bad action"
    }
\end{usecase}

\end{document}
```